# Neo4j Exclude nodes matching any given relations

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

My use-case contains two types of node `Problem` and `Tag` where a `Problem` can have "One-To-Many" relation with `Tag` i.e. there are multiple `(Problem)-[:CONATINS]->(Tag)` relations for a single problem (ignore the syntax). With the given array of tags I want cypher query to get `Problem` which do not contain any of those `Tag`

Sample Nodes:

`Problem {id:101, rank:2.389}` ; `Tag {name: "python"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example dataset:

```
CREATE (p1:Problem {id:1}),
       (p2:Problem {id:2}),
       (p3:Problem {id:3}),

       (t1:Tag {name:'python'}),
       (t2:Tag {name:'cypher'}),
       (t3:Tag {name:'neo4j'}),
       (t4:Tag {name:'ruby'}),

       (t1)-[:TAGS]->(p1),
       (t2)-[:TAGS]->(p1),
       (t2)-[:TAGS]->(p2),
       (t3)-[:TAGS]->(p2),
       (t3)-[:TAGS]->(p3),
       (t4)-[:TAGS]->(p3)
```

[image]

If you want problems that aren't tagged by `python` or `cypher`, you only want problem 3 to be returned.

```
MATCH (t:Tag)
WHERE t.name IN ['python', 'cypher']
MATCH (p:Problem)
WITH p, sum(size((t)-[:TAGS]->(p))) AS matches
WHERE matches = 0
RETURN p;
```

This returns only problem 3.

Comment: Thanks alot @nicole-white :) Worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have to `MATCH` both nodes which don't have connections to `Tag` and nodes which are connected to other `Tag` nodes (but not the ones in your list). I would split this in two queries:

```
// unconnected nodes
MATCH (p:Problem)
WHERE NOT (p)-[:CONTAINS]-()
RETURN p
// combine queries with union (both have to return the same)
UNION
// nodes which fullfill you criterion
MATCH (p:Problem)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Tag)
// collect distinct Problem nodes with a list of associated Tag names
WITH DISTINCT p, collect(t.name) AS tag_name
// use a none predicate to filter all Problems where none
// of the query tag names are found
WHERE none(x IN ['python', 'java', 'haskell'] WHERE x IN tag_name)
RETURN p
```

Comment: No, I want to match for any one of those "One-To-Many" relations. Even if the problem has one of the given tags.. it will be excluded

Comment: True, I overlooked that you want to exclude a node if any of the `Tags` is present. The other answer works but I think you could also do this with a `none` predicate.